# How can you make buttons stretched only when the `navbar` is collapsed (Bootstrap)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/4tusk977/.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">...</a>
        <button aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed navbar-toggle" data-target="#main_menu" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
          <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_menu">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="main_menu_form" style="border: none;">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="sign in">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="sign up">
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want both Sign In and Sign Up buttons to be stretched equally when the navigation bar is collapsed. I have tried using flex box, it succeed, however it also ruins the layout when the navigation bar is not collapsed. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: when you mention streched equally, do you mean width of the inputs as in username and password?

Comment: Sorry! Yes I want it to be stretched as the width with the username and password text field. __But__, only when the navigation bar is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@media` css rule to set values on selectors based on specific properties (like screen with).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse input[type="submit"] {
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

Here is your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4tusk977/2/

Comment: Hmmm, I have tried using media query for portrait and landscape as well, actually. Your idea... is tt common to hard coded the width when using CSS? I am not fond of CSS, but usually when designing responsive UI all things derived form the main view port.

Comment: Check the example, it's there :)

Comment: I did already. But I don't like the `max-width: 768px`. That was why I asked is it a good idea to hard coded the width into 768 pixels. And where is that number comes from? Mind to explain?

Comment: @notalentgeek Bootstrap is already hardcoded with 768px, check the docs. What you should be more concerned about is the 49% here, that feels a bit hacky.

Comment: 768px is the width of phones, which is the width bootstrap is using.

Comment: @DavidG the reason for 49% (and not 50%) is due to margin that bootstrap adds to button :( we can remove the margin/padding and set it to 50% :)

Comment: Yes, I assumed that, but now you have a variable width which means the buttons have a 1% gap on the right side.

Comment: @Dekel I might be blind but I don't see where this margin is coming from. I don't see it on the button.

Comment: I usually try to prevent floating elements, sometimes it required. It's only a question to the OP how he want it to look like.

Comment: @Ced actually it's not the margin :( it's the space that exists between the two `<input>` elements in the html.

Comment: @Dekel God you had me searching and scratching my head. At least I had a laugh !

Comment: Exactly, better to remove the whitespace and use 50% in that case. That's the only robust solution that works across all browsers.

Comment: The `float: left` solution left the bottom margin to 0, which can be added back. How much the default margin for the top? Look at the pic here, http://i.imgur.com/oaPzgql.png.